# LAMP charm in a LXC container configuration query

Tags: juju, lamp

Tired of rebuilding and configuring LAMP. I have been following the Get started guide on Juju.ubuntu.com.  and have managed to expose phpyadmin and lamp following Victor Palau's tutorial.

However on my brand new Dell XPS- so no previous lamp installation - therefore, I have no var/www folder and none was created. As specified by Victor: 
"It also allows you to specify a Bazaar branch. It will clone the branch into the webserver and copy the contents to /var/www."

I think it maybe because I ran juju deploy lamp instead of as specified "Clone the Lamp branch to a folder of your choice. I have it under “~/Mycharm/precise/lamp”."

Can some please clear up why this may have happened and how I should proceed, if indeed, I do need to clone the lamp branch?

Desperate to test php on this set up...
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It also allows you to specify a Bazaar branch. It will clone the branch into the webserver and copy the contents to /var/www"

By this I meant the /var/www inside the instance. the instance is contained nwithin a lxc container. To access this juju ssh into the instance:

> juju ssh lamp/0

then check /var/www inside the instance. Your laptops /var/www will not be created